# Magento 2 composer update with sample data removes uploaded images?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

After running a composer update from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 on a Magento 2 store that was set up with sample data, any images that were uploaded via an import to pub/media/import and assigned in pub/media/catalog/product appear to have been deleted.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: No, it is not. Do you have whole pub/media or pub/media/catalog/product removed?

Comment: In the test store, we had product images in both pub/media/import and pub/media/catalog/product for products added besides the sample data. After the "composer update" upgrade (adjusting composer.json to version 2.0.1 first), all file in pub/media/import were gone, and in pub/media/catalog/product, only the sample data images remained.

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. You can report it on GitHub: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: @RobMangiafico can you please post exact steps you followed for upgrade? also did you have a look at upgrade related issues here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_201-upgrade.html

Comment: I edited composer.json, changed version o 2.0.1, created a few missing .gitignore files that caused errors with sample data, and ran "composer update". After that, files in pub/media/import were gone. I opened up github issue as well.